# Is 'toggle in-call status bar' reliable?

Tags: iphone, statusbar, in-call

I'm working on my first app. My question is: In XCode 3.2.6, is the Hardware, 'Toggle In-Call Status Bar' feature reliable? I have an iPod & iPad to test, but not an iPhone. I am wondering if the simulator is reliable on this feature. My concern is that the double height in-call status bar may cause an issue above my table. Everything works fine on the simulator, but I'm not sure if that's reliable. Unfortunately, I have no access to an actual iPhone in order to test. Can I feel comfortable that if this works okay in the simulator it will also work okay on the actual iPhone? Are there any other iPhone specific issues that tend to cause problems? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: That's what the simulator's for.

Comment: Thanks jtbandes. By your answer, I assume it's reliable...no worries. If not, please advise. Thank again.

Comment: The simulator is meant to exactly simulate the device. If something is ever unreliable you should absolutely file a big.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is my first post here, so if there's a proper way to acknowledge/thank for your post, please let me know.

Comment: There isn't since I've just been posting comments on your question. But I'll post an actual answer below, and you can accept it if you feel it answered the question (also, read the FAQ!). Welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulator is meant to exactly simulate the device so you should be able to rely on its behavior. Otherwise, why would we have a simulator? However you do ever find something unreliable you should absolutely [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com/).